# EJB vs JPA controller?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, design-patterns

Sun's Bluperint reference implementation of Pet store is built on the JPA Controller pattern. I find no official EJB blueprints whatsoever.

When should you choose an EJB session bean vs a simple JPA controller? Should / could you use both?

Also, are there any server side validation patterns for both options? I know Java EE 6 has something in this regard, but I'm interested in Java EE 5 patterns for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, maybe the following links are useful for understanding when to use EJB and JPA and when to use them together:

- [Database table access via JPA Vs. EJB in a Web-Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639101/database-table-access-via-jpa-vs-ejb-in-a-web-application/4639182#4639182)
- [EJB 3 or Hibernate 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639535/ejb-3-or-hibernate-3/4639967#4639967)

As for the second part, I assume you're referring to `Bean Validation`? In Java EE 5 there isn't quite anything like that. What it does have is a system for attaching validators to input fields in the web layer; the JSF validators. This surely is "server side validation".